# Do I need to use thread and a task in JavaFX to run something in background when a thread will do the job?

Tags: multithreading, javafx

I'm using a thread to periodically run a three second background animation.
I adapted the code in question from a Thread Demo example written in Swing and used 
it to replace a not quite working earlier version that used both a thread and a task.

My program stops/suspends the thread when either playing a video or running an animation 
and starts a new thread when ending the video or animation. This seems to work without 
any downside which is why I'm puzzled why my earlier JavaFX searches hadn't turned up 
a similar solution to the one I'm using.  It seems a rather direct approach for running 
short, simple background animations.

Where am I going wrong with this?  What am I missing?  How would I rewrite this code 
using both a Thread and a Task or do I need to?

I should add - the while and run statements are virtually unchanged from the original 
and the only significant addition to the Swing code was to add thread.setDaemon( true ) 
to startThread().

A podcast listener.

```
// background thread
class BackGround extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while ( suspend.getValue() == false ) {
            try {
                 int r = shared.randInt( 5, 10 );
                 Thread.sleep( r * 1000 );            
            } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
                // do nothing
        }
        if ( suspend.getValue() == false )  {
            Platform.runLater( () -> { 
                 int g = shared.cssGradients.length - 1;
                 g = shared.randInt( 0, g );       
                 gradientColor.set( shared.cssGradients[g] );
                 Boolean bif = shared.updatePanes( shared.cssGradients[g], 
                                      leftPane, rightPane );   

            });
        }
      }
    }   
}   // class background

// start thread
public synchronized void startThread() {
    thread = new BackGround();  // Thread thread ...defined elsewhere
    thread.setDaemon( true );
    thread.start();
}

// stop thread
public synchronized void stopThread() {
    suspend.set( true );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason the `Task` class is useful for JavaFX is that it provides a number of callbacks like `succeeded()`, `failed()` or `cancelled()` and methods like `updateProgress()` and  `updateMessage()` that will run in the JavaFX Application thread and therefore let you update the UI without `Platform.runLater( () -> { ... });` This makes the `Task` class a perfect choice for doing background tasks like downloading data or long running computations.

However, since your thread simply runs continuously without ever really finishing its work, it doesn't seem that you would need any of the additional functionality a `Task` would provide you with over a simple `Thread`.

Still, if you really wanted to convert your code to use a `Task`, it would look just like this:

```
class BackGround extends Task<Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        while (suspend.getValue() == false) {
            try {
                int r = shared.randInt(5, 10);
                Thread.sleep(r * 1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // do nothing
            }
            if (suspend.getValue() == false) {
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    int g = shared.cssGradients.length - 1;
                    g = shared.randInt(0, g);
                    gradientColor.set(shared.cssGradients[g]);
                    Boolean bif = shared.updatePanes(shared.cssGradients[g],
                            leftPane, rightPane);

                });
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

// start thread
public synchronized void startThread() {
    Task<Void> bg = new BackGround();
    Thread taskThread = new Thread(bg);
    taskThread.setDaemon(true);
    taskThread.start();
}

// stop thread
public synchronized void stopThread() {
    suspend.set( true );
}
```

As you see, it really doesn't make a difference for you, as you don't need anything that a `Thread` couldn't give you. If however you wanted to have closer communication with the UI thread, e.g. showing a progress bar or showing status updates, then a `Task` would give you the tools to do that.

I guess its also worth mentioning that the use of a `Timeline` would be quite elegant for triggering your animations. It would look somewhat like this:

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        int g = shared.cssGradients.length - 1;
        g = shared.randInt(0, g);
        gradientColor.set(shared.cssGradients[g]);
        Boolean bif = shared.updatePanes(shared.cssGradients[g], leftPane, rightPane);
    }
}
));
timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
timeline.play();
```

The code inside the `handle()` method is run every second in the JavaFX Application thread. Unfortunately this only lets you set a fixed time between executions, while you seem to want to wait a random amount of time each time.

TL;DR: Using a `Thread` is ok, because you don't need the additional functionalities of a `Task` in your use case.

Comment: Thanks again in case my last comment didn't make it.

Comment: I tried using your suggestion and changed my thread into a task but it wouldn't compile:     dots.java:633: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Task
 class BackGround extends Task {
  missing type arguments for generic class Task<V>
  where V is a type-variable:
    V extends Object declared in class Task
java:662: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Task
    Task task = new BackGround();
  missing type arguments for generic class Task<V>
  where V is a type-variable:
    V extends Object declared in class Task
.java:656: error: missing return statement
    }
1 error
2 warnings

Comment: Sorry, it turns out I messed up some things, see my edited answer. The reason it didn't compile was because the return null; statement was missing in the call() method. The warnings from you compiler came from me leaving out the Type arguments for the class (extends Task<Void>). Furthermore I fixed starting the Task correctly in the startThread() method. Sorry about that, It should compile now with these changes.

Comment: Yes, it's accepted.  Your change compiled and the program appears to be running as before when it was solely thread driven.  Thanks again.