# How to syncronize the result of a thread - Java 11

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

```
private List<Box> listBox = new ArrayList<>();
listBox.add(readAll.exec);
```

The method `readAll.exec` executes a thread. The result of the thread arrives about 20 second after the start of execution. Is there a way to syncronize the result of the thread in order to add to the listBox the result when it is ready?

Comment: If `readAll.exec` is a method, did you mean to call it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44511927/do-i-need-to-use-thread-and-a-task-in-javafx-to-run-something-in-background-when

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22772379/updating-ui-from-different-threads-in-javafx

Comment: Are you saying, that you want the new `Box` instance to be added to the `listBox` after the worker thread has done its work?  The easiest way would be to have the worker thread itself add the new `Box` to `listBox`.

Comment: yes. I want a new Box instance to be added to the listbox after the thread has done its work; and yes  to do all inside the thread maybe is the easiest way but i was wondering if it is possible to bind the return value without use a async call back or to make all inside the worker thread.